# Create table with working days and the date for every month depending on the year

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make a VBA to do to do the following:

- fill two columns in a table : first column for Days and second column for 
  Dates and it has only to be with working days(Mon-Fri) for the whole Month
- This is depending on two inputs in two cells (Year, Month)
- When and cell contains Fri as a day and starts again from Mon then the Frame between the two cells has to be Bold.

Would you please help me write the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.
• [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA, you can do this with a combination of a formula and conditional formatting:

Assuming that Month is in A1, and Year in B1, then the following formula in C1 will give you the first day in month and year :

```
   =DATEVALUE("1/"&$A$1&"/"&$B$1)
```

This is for systems set to use dd/mm/yyyy as a date format, Americans would need to change the order so they would use DATEVALUE($A$1&"/1/"&$B$1)

The function WEEKDAY() returns a number between 1 and 7 corresponding to the day of the week, where 1 = Sunday. So we apply this to our function in cell D1

```
 =WEEKDAY(C1)
```

Now we shift to where we want our list to begin (I'll assume A2) and enter

```
  =IF(D1=1,C1+1,IF(D1=7,C1+2,C1))
```

This will be the date of the first weekday in the specified month
In A3 we now enter

```
 =IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=6,A2+3,a2+1)
```

This says, if the row above is a friday then make this the next monday, otherwise make it the next day. Now the only thing we need to do is to stop it displaying at the end of the month: So we wrap this with an If statement to show "" if the date would be after the last day of the month

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(DAY(A2)=DAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&$A$1+1&"/"&$B$1)-1),"",IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=6,A2+3,A2+1)))
```

Now copy this down to row 25. These are your dates - now set the number format to the custom setting  "dddd" to display them as weekdays. Use conditional formatting to add a border if cell = friday